# Bash script in agi-bin fails to execute - asterisk

Tags: bash, scripting, asterisk, telephony

I am trying to execute a bash script from within my dialplan. The bash scripts are from within a directory `projectFiles` in `/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin`. When I try to execute the script, like so:

```
exten => 0,n,System(/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/projectFiles/main.sh ${RECORDED_FILE}.wav ${SOUND_PATH}/menus/wav2.wav)
```

I end up with the following error:

```
WARNING[27515]: app_system.c:125 system_exec_helper: Unable to execute '/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/projectFiles/main.sh /tmp/rec62.wav /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en/projects/menus/wav2.wav'
  == Spawn extension (test-project, 0, 5) exited non-zero on 'DAHDI/15-1'
```

The permissions to the script `main.sh` are set at `asterisk as owner and group`. Where might I be going wrong?

Any help is most welcome,
Sriram.

Comment: You show the ownership, what about the permissions? Have you done `chmod ug+x main.sh` to make it executable?

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, this script is executable with permissions 755.

Comment: What happens when you run the command by hand, exactly as it was quoted in the error message?  If Asterisk is saying it excited non-zero, that likely means there is an error occurring in your script.

Comment: @payne: that was what the problem was. see my answer to the problem below. Is there a way to see what value a script returned when called from dialplan using System command? It might save me from making these mistakes in the future..

Comment: @Sriram, for the purpose use [SHELL function](http://www.itp-redial.com/class/weekly-notes/week4-notes/system-and-shell). It works just like System command, but returns script results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The script within agi-bin, `main.sh` did not execute successfully. Hence the error message. One line within `main.sh` copied `$1` of the input arguments to the present working directory, which I had assumed would be the same directory in which the script was placed. `$HOME` for asterisk (and from where it executes all scripts) is `/etc`. So, a line like the following:

```
cp $1 .
```

would copy `$1` to `/etc`. This caused mayhem further down the script. Changing that line makes everything work OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found another reason, which might be common:
I had created the script on Windows, and copied over in binary mode. The text file contained the hidden ^M at each line end. I removed all of them and everything is fine! The error message is of course extremely misleading!